# autolayout constraints for UIButtons that are in the same row

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

I'm kind of confused by what kind of constraints I should add to my UIButtons in this subview:

[image: screeshot1]

Right now the constraints for these UIButtons are `Aspect Ratio`, `Top Spacing to Container`, `Bottom Spacing to Container` and `Horizontal Spacing` (to each other), like this:
[image: screenshot2]

But when I build it, these UIButtons become this:
[image: screenshot3]

Or this: 
[image: screenshot4]

And it seems like each time I build, some random UIButton becomes irregular.

Also, I'm just generally confused about the constraints in Autolayout, because in this case, for example, I feel like I have done all the constraints that are needed for the UIButtons to stay the way they are in my storyboard. Could someone shed some light on how to approach the auto layout constraints in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose all constraints can not be successful at the same time. Try to relax bottom or top constraints. For example remove bottom spacing to container or change bottom spacing by width flexible (>=).